# Generate Tokens using twitter login

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, authentication, twitter-oauth

**What i want :**

> I need to create a twitter application in which i will be providing user login, once user gets logged in, it should ask user to give permissions for Direct message and tweets, once user allows for it, i need that user's `Consumer API keys` `Access-token` and `access token secret` keys

**What i did :**

> I have created an application for my Twitter account, I have generated
>   `Consumer API keys` `Access-token` and `access token secret` keys for
>   my application, now which way i should go?

I have seen couple of application which asks users to get logged in and their application generates access token n etc for logged in user, and stores to their DB, which can be used later on for sending and receiving DMs and tweets in customer support like applications.

I am looking to do it using java-script.

Your help would be appreciated.

Please let me know if you required further details.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Javascript application that allows users to schedule tweets, retweets, and like tweets, and it uses technology you are asking about.

It does not generate Access Tokens & etc. for the user, because that's Twitter's job... But once the user collects those from Twitter and saves them in my application, you can set up tweets, and schedule when they should go out, and it will Tweet to your account for you using the Twitter API.

Here is my app, you can look through as an example, or even download yourself and run locally on your computer.

- [Here are the code files on GitHub](https://github.com/TJBlackman/Tweeter-Bot)
- [This is the live app! Try It!](http://twitter.trevorblackman.io/)

Your apps needs a server, and if you run a Nodejs server, you can use this NPM package to make interacting with the Twitter API very very easily. IT supports, Tweets, Media Uploads, DMs, Streams, almost everything!

- [NPM Twit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twit)

If you want users to be able to login into your website/app using their Twitter account, you can use Passport.js to easily accomplish this. Search on YouTube, there are many many tutorials.

- [Passport + Twitter Auth Strategy](http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-twitter/)

Good luck!

**EDIT**: To answers you're comments: Yes - you can get/send Tweets and DMs on behalf of another account. You MUST acquire the API KEY & SECRET and the ACCESS TOKEN & SECRET. The client MUST provide these to you. There is no other way to Tweet and DM for other accounts, aside from getting their password and logging directly into Twitter. [Read Twitter Developer Docs.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, My concern is, with the help of this solution would i be able to get and Send DMs and tweets on behalf of particular user from their account? If yes then to access that i need something which allows me to access that, Did you get my requirement?

Comment: I don't want customer to provide me Api key, Api secret, Access token and Access secret, in given application we have to do it manually.

Comment: Thank you @TJBlackman for help, but this not exactly what i need.